# how to make a custom atributte w3 valid?

Tags: custom-attributes, w3c-validation

I have the following code that is used to open a menu over the account anchor:

```
echo "<li><a href='./account/' data-flexmenu='account'>Account"</a></li>";
```

the `data-flexmenu='account'` inform what menu should be shown, in that case, the account menu.

The problem is that im getting error on w3 validator: `there is no attribute "data-flexmenu"`

Is there a way to make that valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about validation. I think validated HTML is important but if your code works in all browsers and still doesn't validate then what's the point? **Custom attributes will work in all browsers, even Internet Explorer 6**. Custom attributes can also be parsed by Javascript and there's no need for the HTML5 doctype to be able to do that.

There's a great article by Nicholas Zakas, where he explains the **value of validation using custom attributes** as an example. See http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/17/the-value-of-html-validation/

Comment: i marked this answer as best answer because i already knew data- is a valid html5 attribut, but if i change the doctype to html5 i will get lots of invalid marks trying to make a working (xhtml invalid) custom attribbute valid, so, your answer seems more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your current doctype doesn't allow the attribute `data-flexmenu`. Either remove this attribute or switch to a HTML5 doctype.

In HTML5 `data-flexmenu` should be valid. You can define a HTML5 doctype like in this **example**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>This is a HTML5 Doctype</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='./account/' data-flexmenu='account'>Account"</a></li>
    <ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Where this is the **HTML5 doctype**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You can also define the **charset** like this if you whish to make it **shorter**:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

And define the **language** of your document like this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

It's possible to make the HTML5 document even shorter but you'll find a lot of information on that.

Comment: A doctype shorter than `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean "doctype" but "document"

Comment: as `<!doctype html> <meta charset=utf-8> <title></title> <p>Some content` should already be valid..